# How to test that Spring MVC configuration is present?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tdd

I would like to have a test which would fail when a Spring MVC configuration is absent, and would pass when it's present. For instance, I have a following test to assure I have Spring Security configured (this test is based on a similar test residing in spring):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SecurityConfiguration.class, JpaConfiguration.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SecurityConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadSecurityConfiguration() {}

    @Test
    public void shouldUseCustomUserDetailsService() {
        assertNotNull(auth.getDefaultUserDetailsService());
        assertTrue(auth.getDefaultUserDetailsService() instanceof UserDetailsServiceImpl);
    }

}
```

Basically it tests just the presence of Spring Security configuration, which forces me to create such a config when adhering to TDD. I tried to create a similar test, based on [this Spring MVC test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfiguration.class, JpaConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn404ForNonExistingPage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/mandible-is-inorganic")).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }

}
```

However, all that test required to pass was downloading spring-webmvc dependency. It managed to pass without my having extended a AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and without @EnableWebMvc-annotated web configuration. What are my options ?

Comment: You could check this in many ways. Most obviously, invoke a method which you know for a fact will use an injected dependency, and check that you get an appropriate null pointer exception. In my work we use `assert dependency != null` in our classes to ensure that they are configured before use.

Comment: @EngineerDollery what dependency would you recommend in my case ? As I understand I need something universal and that would only be present in a fully-configured web app.

Comment: How about SessionFactory in the jpa repository layer?

Comment: @EngineerDollery Well, I like the idea you proposed about having some dependency injected, but I feel that SessionFactory may not suit my needs, as it is related to persistence and not the web layer. I think it should be related to web and rely on spring configuration - and  org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext I tried didn't help me.